# Exclude certain characters using a sql constraint (with regexp)?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to create an Oracle SQL*Plus table, but I'm having trouble with a constraint using regular expressions.

The constraint I'm trying to implement is that the field is 4 characters long and cannot contain the following characters: ,.!£$*<>"=

In reality I would be enough to just only allow alphanumeric characters, so I tried the following regular expression constraint:

```
            CONSTRAINT CHK_Foo CHECK (Foo LIKE '[[:alnum:]]'),
```

However when I attempted to enter `AAAA`field it said I had violated the constraint.

I'm a complete newcomer to Regexp, and a relative newcomer to SQL, so any explanations as to why it doesn't work as well as just an alternative would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. `CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE( foo, '[^,.!£$*<>"=]{4}' ) )` will accept all 4-character strings that do not contain `,.!£$*<>"=`
2. `CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE( bar, '[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}' ) )` will accept all 4-character strings that only contain `a-zA-Z0-9`

(If you want less than strings which are less than or equal to 4 characters in length then you can replace `{4}` with `{0,4}`)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/850c2/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  foo CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  bar CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT chk_foo CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE( foo, '[^,.!£$*<>"=]{4}' ) ),
  CONSTRAINT chk_bar CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE( bar, '[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}' ) )
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 'AAAA', '"AAA' );
```

**Result 1**:

```
ORA-02290: check constraint (USER_4_850C2.CHK_BAR) violated : INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 'AAAA', '"AAA' )
```

**Query 2**:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( '$AAA', 'AAAA' );
```

**Result 2**:

```
ORA-02290: check constraint (USER_4_850C2.CHK_FOO) violated : INSERT INTO test VALUES ( '$AAA', 'AAAA' )
```

**Query 3**:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 'AAAA', 'AAAA' )
```

**Result 3**:

Answer (score 2):

```
CONSTRAINT CHK_Foo CHECK (regexp_LIKE(Foo, '^\w{4}$'))
```

Comment: Please could you explain what that regexp does?

Comment: `\w` is the same as `[[:alnum:]_]` and will allow alpha-numeric characters AND underscore ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDGHBHF)). If you just want alpha-numeric characters then you need to use `[[:alnum:]]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. `{4}` means that the previous match is repeated a total of 4 times and `^` and `$` are boundary matches matching, respectively, the start and end of the string (but if you have a column which is `CHAR(4)` then these boundary matches are unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

You should construct a correct Oracle regexp and then use REGEXP_LIKE and not just LIKE.

See here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDIDJJC

Comment: I'd tried REGEXP_LIKE and it didn't work, but I think I had an invalid regular expression. Egor Skriptunoff's example worked brilliantly so I'll try a few different ones. Thanks a lot :).